# css hide background behind round corner

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

[image]

```
   /* Dropdown item last element */
    .js .main-nav .menu li:last-child a {


        border-bottom: 2px solid;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
```

As you can see the part outside the round corner is white ( same color as the background of the unsorted list ) and I want that it has the same color as the background in this case grey.

I mean nobody sees it but it is for the theory ;)

Comment: Please can you provide the full code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: make sure the parent `ul` has `background: transparent`

Answer (score 1):

Set same `border-radius` for `ul` as for last `li`.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
ul {
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, brown, white);/* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, brown, white);/* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, brown, white);/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, brown, white);/* Standard syntax */
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```